# SQL - Count number of rows in a table before updating it

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, mutating-table

Im doing a college project on Oracle SQL and I keep getting the error "*table (...) is mutating, trigger/function may not see it*" when I try to update a table. My *participateTeams* table has 3 columns ***(eventName varchar(), teamId number, teamPlace number)***.

The Objective here is that when I update the teamPlace of a given team in an event, the place MUST be lower or equal than the number of participant teams in that same event.

My trigger is as follows:

```
Before update on participateTeams
for each row
Declare participants number;
Begin
     select count(*) into participants from participateteams where :New.eventName = participateteams.eventName;

        if(:NEW.teamplace>participants) then
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20250,'O lugar da equipa é inválido');
        end if;
End;
/
```

From what I've researched it's because I'm trying to read the same table that called the trigger.
I have also have tried exporting the *select* part of the code into a function, but the issue persists.

**The participants in the event are the teams theirselves and not the individuals that form those same teams**. Example: If team A, team B and team C participate in an event E, the count for that same event E should be 3.

Any tips? Thank you.

Comment: One approach might be to use a statement-level trigger that checks the whole table. This won't scale for very large volumes but it might do for a college project. A refinement might be to have the row-level trigger store the updated team ID in a package array variable, then have the statement-level trigger only check those. Or, there is a solution using a refresh-on-commit materialised view with a constraint on it.

Answer (score 0):

The mutating table error is just a pain.  And what you are trying to do is rather tricky.  Here is one approach:

1. Add a column to `teams` with the count of participants.
2. Maintain this column with `insert`/`update`, and `delete` triggers on `participateteams`.
3. Write a user-defined function to fetch the count for a given team.
4. Add a `check` constraint in `participateteams` using the user-defined function.

Comment: I apologize as my description of the problem may have not been clear, but **the participants are the teams theirselves, not the individuals in the team**. For example in an event E there's team A, team B and team C competing, therefore the count for event E should return 3.

Answer (score 0):

The logically correct trigger for what you want to achieve is this :-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_CHK
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF teamPlace ON participateteams
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
participants NUMBER;
BEGIN
 select count(*) into participants from participateteams where :New.eventName = 
 participateteams.eventName;
    if(:NEW.teamplace>participants) then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20250,'O lugar da equipa é inválido');
    end if;
End;    
update participateteams set teamPlace = 2 where eventName = 'B';
```

But when it gives Mutating table error when  trying to update table participateteams,to solve this tricky situation , what I did is :-

step1 :Declare the table columns needed in a package header

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_TEAMS AS
v_eventName participateteams.eventName%type;
v_teamPlace participateteams.teamPlace%type;
end;
```

step2 : Initialize the variables in a row level trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_row
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF teamPlace
ON participateteams
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
PKG_TEAMS.v_eventName := :NEW.eventName;
PKG_TEAMS.v_teamPlace := :NEW.teamPlace;
END;
```

step3 :Now ,rather than using :NEW pseudo columns, using globally initialized variables

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_stmt
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF teamPlace ON participateteams
DECLARE 
v_participants NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_participants FROM participateteams
WHERE eventName = PKG_TEAMS.v_eventName;
 if(PKG_TEAMS.v_teamPlace>v_participants) then
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20250,'CANNOT UPDATE,AGAINST RULES');
        end if;
End;
```